# Front end deployment of data from the database

Tags: python, node.js, postgresql, api, frontend

I have a POSTGRES database ready for my work. Now I would like to know what are my options for the front end to display the data? Do I need to use API? I can use Python or node.js? Anything but PHP basically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need an API (nodejs, python...) then your frontend has a HTTP access point to your data.

Comment: Would Python and Flask be a better option or node.js? I need decent amount of computing but speed is a necessary factor.

Comment: Python + Flask (eventually flask-restful which is better for API implementation). NodeJS can suit well your need, it depends which language you prefer :) Both do good job!